# Is there a way to pass data from one process of Powershell script to another already running process of the same script?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, ipc

I'm trying to implement custom uri scheme processing. When you call a uri of a custom scheme, a new instance of an executable bound to that scheme launches.

I want that new instance to pass argument data to an old already running instance. E.g Telegram does this, when you try to open a link to a Telegram channel from a browser and the browser opens tg://... link that opens a telegram app showing that channel. I assume somehow data is transferred from one instance to another and after that the new instance is closed.

How can I pass data from a new instance to an old one with Powershell?

Comment: It is not powershell related. There are many ways of communication between processes. The simpliest is through files (one app writes files to folder X, another app periodically scans folder X and reads files), possibly this is enough. There are also named pipes, socket communication, COM ,DDE, RPC and many more ways.

Comment: @filimonic I've completely forgot about named pipes, thank you!